# How to change date and time ascending in database MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have over 100,000 entries with the same date and time. How to change to add 10 minutes and make the date also change as the next day?

I have:

```
2020-01-01 23:50:00
2020-01-01 23:50:00
2020-01-01 23:50:00
2020-01-01 23:50:00
2020-01-01 23:50:00
```

etc....

I want:

```
2020-01-01 23:50:00
2020-01-02 00:00:00
2020-01-02 00:10:00
2020-01-02 00:20:00
......
2020-01-31 00:50:00
2020-02-01 00:00:00
2020-02-01 00:10:00
2020-02-01 00:20:00
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method uses variables in an `update`:

```
set @minutes = -10;

update t
    set col = col + interval (@minutes := @minutes + 10) minute
    where col = '2020-01-01 23:50:00';
```

If you just want a `select`, then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (col + interval 10 * row_number() over (order by col) - 10 minute)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1de86c2ef211d3d231d7bcfae58c979d) is a db<>fiddle showing that both work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @MarekSerus . . . What doesn't work?  I added a db<>fiddle showing that *both* work, exactly as advertised.

Comment: I did not understand too much before or did something wrong. Thank you very much! Works Perfect!